# Pulling text out of JSON using VARCHAR

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to pull out text value out of column with json using `varchar` but get an invalid argument error on snowflake while running on mode. This json has a bit of different structure that what I'm used to seeing.

Have tried these to pull out the text:

```
changes:comment:new_value::varchar
changes:new_value::varchar
changes:comment::varchar
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "comment": 
   { 
      "new_value": "Hello there. Welcome to our facility.", 
      "old_value": ""
   }
}
```

Wish to pull out the data in this column so the output reads:

```
Hello there. Welcome to our facility.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract fields from `VARCHAR`. If your string is JSON, you have to convert it to the `VARIANT` type, e.g. through `PARSE_JSON` function.

Example below:

```
create or replace table x(v varchar) as select * from values('{
   "comment": 
   { 
      "new_value": "Hello there. Welcome to our facility.", 
      "old_value": ""
   }
}');
select v, parse_json(v):comment.new_value::varchar from x;
--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
                              V                               | PARSE_JSON(V):COMMENT.NEW_VALUE::VARCHAR |
--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
 {                                                            | Hello there. Welcome to our facility.    |
    "comment":                                                |                                          |
    {                                                         |                                          |
       "new_value": "Hello there. Welcome to our facility.",  |                                          |
       "old_value": ""                                        |                                          |
    }                                                         |                                          |
 }                                                            |                                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```